# How do I insert Unique values in MySQL using using Java

Tags: java, list

I have to display two lists, where li lists the old values and newli lists the new values. Based on this requirement, How do I insert unique values in mysql using java?

```
List<String> li =new ArrayList<String>();
        li.add("abcd");
        li.add("efgh");
        li.add("ijkl");
        List<String> newli=new ArrayList<String>();
        newli.add("mnop");
        newli.add("qrst");
        newli.add("uvwx");
        newli.add("yz");
        newli.add("abcd");

            Iterator it = newli.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                String str=(String) it.next();
                if(str.equals(li))
                {
                    System.out.println("This element Already present");
                    break;
                }
                else
                    System.out.println(str);


            }
            System.out.println("Already present");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(li);
uniqueSet.addAll(newLi);
```

That will give you all the unique values from the two lists in one Set.